# Performance Issue with PySpark DataFrame Transformation Using mapping function

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**Question:**

I'm currently experiencing performance issues when applying a mapping function to a PySpark DataFrame, especially when dealing with larger datasets in a production environment. I have a DataFrame df that contains key-value pairs (maptype), and I'm using a reference DataFrame df_ref to create a mapping dictionary mapping_dict. The mapping is applied to the key_value_pair column using a custom apply_mapping function.

```
def apply_mapping(mapping: Dict[str, str]) -> Callable[[col, col], col]:


    def convert_mapping_into_when_conditions(key: col, value: col) -> col:
        initial_map_key, initial_map_value = mapping.popitem()
        # Use lit(initial_value) to ensure consistent data type in the array
        initial_condition = when(key == initial_map_key, array(value, lit(initial_map_value)))
        return reduce(
            lambda x, y: x.when(key == y[0], array(value, lit(y[1]))),
            mapping.items(),
            initial_condition,
        )
    return convert_mapping_into_when_conditions

# Apply mapping to key_value_pair column and create a new column key_value_pair_mapped
df = df.withColumn(
    "key_value_pair_mapped",
    transform_values("key_value_pair", apply_mapping(broadcasted_mapping_dict)),
)
```

The problem arises when using the apply_mapping function on a larger dataset. It seems to be inefficient, and I'm seeking advice on how to optimize this code for better performance.

Is there any suggestion on how to improve the efficiency of the apply_mapping function or any other part of the code? I appreciate any guidance or insights.

Thank you in advance!

**code**

```
from typing import Dict, Callable
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, broadcast, col, transform_keys, when, lit, transform_values, array, concat_ws, map_filter
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType, BooleanType, DoubleType

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("YourAppName").getOrCreate()

def apply_mapping(mapping: Dict[str, str]) -> Callable[[col, col], col]:
    """
    Apply mapping to key-value pairs in a DataFrame column.

    Parameters:
    - mapping: A dictionary representing the mapping of keys to data types.

    Returns:
    A function that converts key-value pairs based on the provided mapping.
    The returned function uses PySpark's `when` and `array` functions to conditionally
    create arrays based on the mapping. The initial condition ensures a valid starting
    point for the subsequent iterations.
    """
    def convert_mapping_into_when_conditions(key: col, value: col) -> col:
        initial_map_key, initial_map_value = mapping.popitem()
        # Use lit(initial_value) to ensure consistent data type in the array
        initial_condition = when(key == initial_map_key, array(value, lit(initial_map_value)))
        return reduce(
            lambda x, y: x.when(key == y[0], array(value, lit(y[1]))),
            mapping.items(),
            initial_condition,
        )
    return convert_mapping_into_when_conditions

# Example data
data = {
    "blaa": "a",
    "pear": "z",
    "orange": "gh",
    "grape": "161",
    "banana": "20",
    "cherry": "1.50",
    "kiwi": "0",
    "melon": "0",
    "strawberry": "1",
    "blueberry": "1",
}
version = "v1"

# Example data reference table
df_list_data = [
    ("apple", "str", "v1"),
    ("pear", "str", "v1"),
    ("orange", "str", "v1"),
    ("grape", "double", "v1"),
    ("banana", "double", "v1"),
    ("cherry", "double", "v1"),
    ("kiwi", "bool", "v1"),
    ("melon", "bool", "v1"),
    ("strawberry", "bool", "v1"),
    ("blueberry", "bool", "v1"),
]

# Column names
columns = ["key_value_pair", "version"]

# Column names ref
columns_ref = ["id", "data_type", "version"]

# Create a Spark DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([(data, version)], columns)

# Simplify v1 concatenation and subsequent split
df = df.withColumn(
    "key_value_pair",
    transform_keys("key_value_pair", lambda k, _: concat_ws("_", k, col("version")))
)

# Create a Spark DataFrame ref
df_ref = spark.createDataFrame(df_list_data, columns_ref)

df_ref = df_ref.withColumn("id", concat_ws("_", col("id"), col("version")))

# Collect data from df_ref
mapping_data = df_ref.collect()

# Convert the collected data to a Python dictionary
mapping_dict = {row["id"]: row["data_type"] for row in mapping_data}

# Broadcast the mapping dictionary to be used in Spark transformations
broadcasted_mapping_dict = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(mapping_dict).value

# Apply mapping to key_value_pair column and create a new column key_value_pair_mapped
df = df.withColumn(
    "key_value_pair_mapped",
    transform_values("key_value_pair", apply_mapping(broadcasted_mapping_dict)),
)

# Remove "_v1" from keys in key_value_pair_mapped column
df = df.withColumn(
    "key_value_pair_mapped",
    transform_keys("key_value_pair_mapped", lambda k, _: split(k, "_")[0]),
)

# Create separate columns for each data type
df = df.withColumn(
    "col_str",
    transform_values(
        map_filter("key_value_pair_mapped", lambda k, v: v[1] == "str"),
        lambda k, v: v[0],
    ).cast(MapType(StringType(), StringType())),
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "col_bool",
    transform_values(
        map_filter("key_value_pair_mapped", lambda k, v: v[1] == "bool"),
        lambda k, v: v[0],
    ).cast(MapType(StringType(), BooleanType())),
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "col_double",
    transform_values(
        map_filter("key_value_pair_mapped", lambda k, v: v[1] == "double"),
        lambda k, v: v[0],
    ).cast(MapType(StringType(), DoubleType())),
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with an input sample and the expected result for that input ? Maybe we can find a simpler solution.

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb,
I'm transforming a DataFrame by mapping key-value pairs to their corresponding data types using PySpark. The goal is to efficiently process and categorize the elements in the key_value_pair column based on a predefined mapping. I provided sample input data and expect the transformed DataFrame to have separate columns for each data type. I added the missing code.

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb, can you have a look?